# Randomly sample dataset x number of times, and create new dataframe output

Tags: r

I have a dataset (hundreds of rows) that links IDs to individuals. Each ID is unique, and is associated with an individual, which may be linked with multiple IDs. In the example below, individual A is linked with ID 1 and 3.

Example:

```
IDs individual
1   A
2   B
3   A
4   C
5   D
6   D
```

I would like to randomly sample 1-100 IDs, 500 times (so each of those 500 random samples could be comprised of 1-100 IDs), with the opportunity for IDs to be resampled within a given sample.

I would then like to create a new dataframe that summarises the number of unique individuals that were detected given the number of IDs that were sampled across random samples.

An example of the first 6 rows of the new output dataframe could look something like this (however, there would be 500 random.samples):

```
random.sample  number.of.IDs unique.individuals
1              10            7
2              86            74
3              4             1
4              61            50
5              34            22
6              98            80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quite straightforward approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(100)

example_data <- data.frame( IDs=1:300, individual = sample( LETTERS, 300, replace=T))

# these are the sizes of each sample
n <- ceiling(runif( 500, 0,100 ))

# these are the 500 samples, arranged as a list of data.frame's
my_samples <- n %>% map( sample_n, tbl=example_data, replace=TRUE )

# this will be a single data.frame with only the number of unique
# values in each row
df_of_unique <- my_samples %>%
    map(
        ~map(.x, ~length(unique(.x))) %>% as.data.frame
    ) %>%
    bind_rows %>%
    set_names(c("number.of.IDs","unique.individuals"))

# add the first column as shown in your desired output
result <-
    cbind(random.sample=seq_len(length(n)), df_of_unique)
```

The output:

```
> head(result)
  random.sample number.of.IDs unique.individuals
1             1             3                  3
2             2            11                 10
3             3            25                 16
4             4            73                 25
5             5             4                  4
6             6            55                 22
```

Comment: Since you're sampling with replacement, I'm not sure there's much difference between taking 500 samples of `n` size or one sample of `sum(n)` and then grouping afterwards with a sequence number. Might be able to avoid some of the looping `map` parts of this code.

Comment: I agree, the map-in-map is not pretty, but step-by-step it's closer to the operation he outlined, and perhaps makes for an easier to adapt starting point for his work

Answer (score 2):

Since you're sampling with replacement, I'm not sure there's much difference between taking 500 samples of `n` size or one big sample and then grouping afterwards. E.g.:

```
set.seed(100)
example_data <- data.frame(IDs=1:300, individual = sample(LETTERS, 300, replace=T))

n <- 100
runs <- 500
sel <- ceiling(runif(runs, 0, n))
smp <- example_data[sample(seq_len(nrow(example_data)), sum(sel), replace=TRUE),]
smp$run <- rep(seq(runs), sel)
out <- aggregate(cbind(IDs, individual) ~ run, data=smp, FUN=\(x) length(unique(x)))

head(out)
#  run IDs individual
#1   1   3          3
#2   2  10          9
#3   3  24         16
#4   4  66         24
#5   5   4          4
#6   6  51         23
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution. Note you haven't stated explicitly that the IDs have to be unique, e.g. whether IDs can be repeated in any given sample. This example assumes no repeat IDs. If repeat IDs are allowed in a given sample, change `replace = FALSE` to `replace = TRUE`.

```
set.seed(1) # Ensures df values can be replicated

df <- data.frame(IDs = 1:1000, 
                 individuals = sample(letters, 1000, replace = TRUE))

# Create empty df for results
results <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol=3))
colnames(results) <- c("random.sample",  "number.of.IDs", "unique.individuals")

# Loop number of desired samples
for(i in 1:500) {
  
  # Randomly sample between 1-100 IDs
  x <- sample(df$IDs, size = sample.int(100, 1), replace = FALSE)
  # Get sample iteration, and count of both unique IDs and individuals
  y <- c(i, length(unique(x)), length(unique(df[x,"individuals"])))
  # Add counts to results df
  results[nrow(results)+1,] <- y
  
}

head(results)
#   random.sample number.of.IDs unique.individuals
# 1             1            71                 26
# 2             2            42                 24
# 3             3            78                 25
# 4             4            18                 12
# 5             5            71                 23
# 6             6            41                 20
```

Comment: you could use lapply and Reduce with rbind (which essentially is the tidyverse based approach above). That way you wouldn't have to do the step-wise growing of the data.frame in the for loop.

Comment: @Sirius - how would that look? Be great to know how as I've never successfully worked out how to combine all three. Thanks

Comment: Basically like this: Reduce( rbind, my_samples ) # so this goes instead of bind_rows()

That being said, do.call( rbind, my_samples) # is just as easy and actually faster (tested with microbenchmark)

Comment: the my_samples would be generated doing something like: my_samples <- lapply( n, function(.x) { d <- example_data[ sample(seq_len(nr),.x,replace=TRUE), ]; lapply( d, function(.x)length(unique(.x)) ) |> as.data.frame() } ) ## sorry, comments don't let you show code well, but you could copy it and add spaces and newlines